# mysql date and values difference from same table

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have single table with date and value. I want to show date difference and value.

Table

```
   date     |  value
-------------------------    
7/24/2015       496
7/31/2015       496
8/7/2015        496
8/14/2015       496
8/21/2015       496
8/28/2015       400
9/4/2015        400
9/11/2015       400
1/29/2016       400
2/5/2016        400
```

Output

```
date | Difference | value
-------------------------
7/24/2015       496
8/28/2015   96  400
9/11/2015       400
```

Condition : 
1. if there is any difference in value based on date it should show in difference column.
2. Repeated same value not required to show again.
3. Decrease will show difference in another column.

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account_str1` (
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `acc_no` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cust_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL
)

 // cdsl_res taken as array count 

 <table class="table-bordered table-striped table">
<thead>
    <th>Date </th>
    <th>Transferred </th>
     <th>Points </th>
</thead>

 <?php
for($i=0;$i<$cdsl_res;$i++){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$mydateArray[$i].'</td>';
    $share1 = $mypositionArray[$i];
    $share2 = $mypositionArray[$i-1];

    if($share_1 < $share_2){
        $diff   = $share_2 - $share_1;
        echo '<td>'.$diff.'</td>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<td></td>';

    }

    echo '<td>'.$mypositionArray[$i].'</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looking at the previous value and the number of values in a row.  In MySQL, one method is using correlated subqueries.  The rest is just logic in the `where` clause:

```
select date,
       (case when value <> prev_value then prev_value - value end) as diff,
       value
from (select a.*,
             (select value
              from account_str1 a2
              where a2.date < a.date
              order by a2.date desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_value,
             (select count(*)
              from account_str1 a2
              where a2.date <= a.date and a2.value = a.value
             ) as seqnum
      from account_str1 a
     ) t
where prev_value is null or value <> prev_value or seqnum = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by a complex SQL query, like suggested in the previous answer. But the PHP solution is easier, I think. Since you anyway go through all records one by one in a loop.

```
$sql='SELECT `Date`, `points` FROM `account_str1` ORDER BY `Date`';
$q=$db->query($sql);
$prev=0;
while ($r=$q->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dif = $r['points']>$prev?$r['points']-$prev:'';
    $prev=$r['points'];
    echo "<tr><td>$r[Date]</td><td>$dif</td><td>$r[points]</td></tr>\n";
}
```